# Replace character with a absolute value

Tags: javascript, python, replace, syntax

When searching my db all special characters work aside from the "+" - it thinks its a space. Looking on the backend which is python, there is no issues with it receiving special chars which I believe it is the frontend which is Javascript

what i need to do is replace "+" == "%2b". Is there a way for me to use create this so it has this value going forth?

Comment: You can run a script to replace the existing of DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decodeURIComponent('%2b'), or encodeUriComponent('+');`

if you decode the response from the server, you get the + sign-

if you want to replace all ocurrence just place the whole string insde the method and it decodes/encodes the whole string.

Comment: i am glad i helped, you can accept the anwer if it fit your needs :)